# How to Remote Manage Windows Server 2012 in Server Manager?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-core, windows

We are managing multiple Windows Server 2012 through Server Manager installed on Windows 8. Most things work smoothly with these two exceptions.

1. On [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831456.aspx#BKMK_tasks) it states that Server Manager can remotely manage Windows Server 2012 and *"Perform management tasks associated with the operational lifecycle of servers, such as starting or stopping services; and start other tools that allow you to configure a server’s network settings, users and groups, and Remote Desktop connections."* However, I don't see how can I start the tools to config network settings or remote desktop settings. I can manage these locally by going to the "Local Server" tab in Server Manager.
2. We have several Server Core installations and one of them is running as a DC. I can use "Computer Management" for the DC remotely, but not for all other Server Core installations. Remote Administration is enabled on all servers.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed with 'other tools' they mean PowerShell, right click on the remote server in Server Manager and select 'Windows PowerShell'. Now you can do pretty much everything on the remote server, but if you not familiar with PowerShell or all the new PowerShell commands on Server 2012 you need to learn about these first.